# Select column pairs for data sampling

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to select records from table so as to cover all A and B column values for data sampling, such that for each A data, B values are selected but if same B values exist for each A value, then one of them will be selected basis every A value is covered.

Sample table data:

```
|  A  |   B  |
|:---:|:----:|
|  a1 |  1   |
|  a1 |  2   |
|  a1 |  3   |
|  a1 |  4   |
|  a1 |  5   |
|  a2 |  1   |
|  a3 |  2   |
|  a3 |  3   |
|  a3 |  4   |
```

expected outcome:

```
|  A  |   B  |
|:---:|:----:|
|  a1 |  5   |
|  a2 |  1   |
|  a3 |  2   |
|  a3 |  3   |
|  a3 |  4   |
```

Here, a1 had 1-5 B values, and a2 had 1 B value, so we selected a2 - 1 and same with a3: we selected a3 - 2,3,4 B values for sampling as a1 had an extra 5 B value, so every A value is covered and B value also covered for data sampling.

Anyone has any idea for about how I can achieve this with query?

Thanks.

Comment: Not clear: why not getting for example `(a1,3) (a1,4) (a1,5) (a2,1) (a3,2)` ?!? This is totally different result set which also fits your description.

Comment: I'm not selecting a1- 1,2,3,4 because 2,3,4 values are common for a1 and a3, and since I need to sample data I've to select a3 for these values as we can select the extra 5 value for a1.  Similarly, 1 is common for a1 and a2, I selected (a2,1) because a1 has extra 5 value that can be picked for sampling.  So this way all a1, a2, and a3 are covered, and B column 1-5 values are also covered for sampling.

Comment: In my sample result you also have a3. There is no configuration for "common" in your data. You need to clarify the exact rules to select specific row over the other. We cannot read your mind as so the SQL Server cannot do it. We cannot know what is "common" in your mind. You need to use the data in the table (or add data) to explain why one row is proffered over the other. Why a3,3 and not a1,3 for example when both a1 and a3 already in the result? Check again my sample result and explain what is not fit your rules there. You can find all values of A and all values of B as requested.

Comment: My apologies for not explaining well, the scenario is actually little confusing. By "common", I'm referring to B column data. And we are sampling pair data for A and B columns. The requirement is like that, if for example, a1 is paired with 1-5 in B, and a2 paired with one matching B column value ie. 1, then we would choose to select '(a2, 1)'. because I also need 'a2' in my data sampling. Similarly, since a3 is paired with 2,3,4  and a1 also with 2,3,4, so we select all of those to be included in result to include a3 in data sampling as a1 still has 5 value left to be paired with.

Comment: Now,coming to your sample result: `(a1,3) (a1,4) (a1,5) (a2,1) (a3,2)` out of these data sampling is done such a way: 
`(a1,3)` - can't select this as 3 is also paired with a3. We've "5" which can be paired with a1, so a1 will be incl. in sampling with 5
`(a1,4)` - can't select because of same reason above
`(a1,5)` - I've selected in expected output because 5 is paired with a1 only
`(a2,1)` - selected in expected output because, otherwise a2 won't get part of sampling, n (a1, 1) will be rejected
`(a3,2)` - have selected in output because, 2 is also paired with a1 & we can select 5 for a1.